# If two different integers between 1 and 100 inclusive are chosen at random, what is the probability that the difference of the two numbers is 15?

Tags: calculus, probability, combinations

My work:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 (1-20)

20-5

19-4

18-3

17-2

16-1  so 5

5^5=3125 Am I missing a step? Or am I correct?

Comment: They ask for a probability, so you need a number between $0$ and $1$. Also, no idea why $5^5$ is relevant to your problem. And why did you try to solve it only for the 1-20 range?

Comment: There are some characters in your question that do not render properly.  You need to add some words to explain what you are doing.  Your question seems to work only up to $20$ while the title calls for $100$.

Comment: You are missing the probability?  What does $5^5$ represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  How many pairs have a difference of $15?$  How many pairs are there?  Divide to get the probability.

Added:  if the first number is $1-15$ or $86-100$, a $0.3$ probability, you have $\frac 1{99}$, while if the first number is $16-85$ you have $\frac 2{99}$, so the overall chance is $$0.3 \cdot \frac 1{99}+0.7 \cdot \frac 2{99}=\frac {17}{990}$$
Another way to see it is that there are $85$ pairs $15$ apart out of ${100 \choose 2}=4950$ total pairs, so the chance is $$\frac {85}{4950}=\frac {17}{990}$$

Comment: So it should be 85 as my answer?

Comment: That is the answer to the first question.  You are asked for a probability, which must be between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: 85/50 but it is not between 0 and 1 though. That means I did something wrong.

Comment: There are many more pairs than $50$.  There are $100 \choose 2$.  Intuitively, the answer has to be between $1/100$ and $2/100$ because some first cards you could draw only allow $1$ choice for the second card and some allow $2$.

Comment: How did you find that the number of pairs that have a difference of 15 is 85?

Comment: @TotomaLover2312:  All the numbers from $1$ through $85$ have a number $15$ available.